# (update)I want to use runserver to make some objects with admin but it says the object has no attribute 'urls'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have registered the models in admin.py

the whole things I've changed in this app are in admin.py and models.py

I didn't created the urls.py

When I commented the registration in admin.py i was able to migrate the models.py changes but now when i registering the models with admin  i can't use runserver and to create objects i should use the shell command

i just wanted to add objects from admin not to use the shell and i think if i don't debug this will be a problem sometime later again

this is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Clients(models.Model):
    name =     models.CharField(max_length=300)
    company =  models.CharField(max_length=300)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.company

class Manufacturers(models.Model):
    name =      models.CharField(max_length=300)
    location =  models.TextField("address")
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class Products(models.Model):
    cost_per_item =    models.PositiveBigIntegerField("Cost")
    name_of_product =  models.CharField("name", max_length=300)
    manufacturer =     models.ForeignKey(Manufacturers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
            return self.name
    
class ClientOrders(models.Model):
    fulfill_date =  models.PositiveIntegerField("Fulfill Month")
    order_number =  models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    client =        models.ForeignKey(Clients, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products =      models.ManyToManyField(Products)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.client
```

this is admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Clients, ClientOrders, Manufacturers, Products

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Clients, ClientOrders)
admin.site.register( Manufacturers, Products)
```

this is the traceback:

```
(Django_learn) D:\learnD\learnF1>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\learnD\learnF1\config\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 247, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 299, in urls
    return self.get_urls(), 'admin', self.name
  File "C:\Users\Armin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 279, in get_urls
    path('%s/%s/' % (model._meta.app_label, model._meta.model_name), include(model_admin.urls)),
AttributeError: 'ClientOrders' object has no attribute 'urls'
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Make urls.py in the app.

Comment: There is a broken reference to "urls" - not necessarily to "urls.py". According to the single-line of traceback you've shown so far, the error is in code which references ClientOrders.  ClientOrders has no attribute "urls", so that much fits. Without additional lines of the traceback, we have no way of knowing where the bug is. If the "full traceback" is more than a couple dozen lines, try posting just the last twenty or so lines of traceback.  Cut & paste is your friend.  Once we know what's trying to access `ClientOrders.urls`, we can help you fix the problem.

Comment: I've added the traceback

Comment: That's... odd. It looks like you're calling a _urls.py_ on a separate disk, and _that_ portion of the config is trying to build out Admin pages for each of your models. Normally, that process would use (I think) a per-subproject `urls.py`, at the same level as your `models.py`, and that's MIA. Are you intending to have an admin panel & UI for this, or are you just using Django's ORM?  You can certainly try adding a blank `urls.py`, but if you're not yet ready to add in a UI, you've probably got something enabled in `settings.py` which you don't need. I also want to know why D:\ is in there.

Comment: I'm using Django defaults for admin and I've created the project in the drive D i'll post the full traceback

Comment: Can you share your admin.py?

Comment: I've added the admin.py